# How to grab an image file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an app in the Public_html/app root and I want to access image files outside the public_html root (subdomain). How to do it? Please help

this is my code but it doesn't work:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url() ?><?php echo $hasil->file_kk; ?>" width="40%" alt="">
```

I use codeigniter

Comment: a subdomain? that means you won't be using `base_url`

Comment: so what should i use? Please help